# Can Python or R join local dataframes with database tables like Proc SQL in SAS?

Tags: python, sql, r, sas

PROC SQL can join a local table to one from a database. For example, joining db.sales and work.customer_info. To my knowledge, there aren't any packages in R or Python that can do this; either the local table must be uploaded to the database and the join done there, or the table (entire or subset) must be queried into local memory as a dataframe and then joined with the flat file.

Is there actually a way to do this in Python or R? Or is SAS superior for querying like this?

Comment: How do you suppose SAS joins a local, in memory table with a remote table on a DB? I suspect the work is done in memory on your local environment. If that is true, similar facilities exist in R and Python.

Comment: Don't overestimate SAS's PROC SQL. It is basically a codegenerator generating DATA -steps. Lacking any useful catalogs (indexes, foreign keys, ...), it is only usable for trivial SQL operations. A three or four tables- join or anti-join will not perform very well.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no client (here being Python Pandas, R, and SAS) ever actually *joins* server stored database tables to client objects like data frames or data sets. Clients handle remote connections to backend systems and then imports result sets for additional local uses. Specifically:

- Data frames in Python Pandas and R runs in RAM where you can join/merge/append *any* data frame in current global environment originated from flat files or other structures. Python and R can also connect to relational databases and query needed tables to be imported as data frames in current session's global environment. From there they can join/merge/append to other local data frames.
- Data sets in SAS for default libraries runs on hard disk or file system folders where you can join/merge/append *any* data set in defined libraries or as [9.4 docs](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lestmtsglobal&docsetTarget=n1nk65k2vsfmxfn1wu17fntzszbp.htm&locale=en) mention:

  > *libref* is a shortcut name or a “nickname” for the aggregate storage location where your SAS files are stored.

  However, when connecting to a database using `libname` like in the SAS/Access API, the library is simply a *visual* not actual physical database tables and views, or as [9.4 docs](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lestmtsglobal&docsetTarget=n1nk65k2vsfmxfn1wu17fntzszbp.htm&locale=en) specify (emphasis added):

  > *libref* specifies any SAS name that serves as an alias to associate SAS with a database, schema, server, or group of tables and views. Like the global SAS LIBNAME statement, the SAS/ACCESS LIBNAME statement creates shortcuts or nicknames for data storage locations. A SAS libref is an alias for a virtual or physical directory. **A SAS/ACCESS libref is an alias for the DBMS database, schema, or server where your tables and views are stored.**

  The one exception for physical directories would be file-level databases including MS Access and SQLite that are not server-level databases like Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle:

  ```
  libname mydata "C:\Path\To\Database.accdb";

  libname mydata odbc complete = "Driver={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};Database=C:\Path\To\database.db";
  ```

Altogether, similar to Python and R, SAS does not run on physical *database tables* but likely imported results to actual backends. So in your example, each call of database table in `proc sql`, SAS runs a similar remote connection as Python and R would to retrieve results and then subsequent client-side processing `join` to local dataset. All processing may be handled in memory with results saved to hard disk (i.e., temp *Work* folder). What the user sees as one step may be multiple steps by SAS.